# How to serve compile assets with rails and nginx on docker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've been preparing for production with my rails application and I'm having a lot of trouble with nginx. Compared to development where the assets weren't precompiled, nothing works now. I use sprockets to handle the css, images and fonts and webpacker for the javascript. Problem is, whenever I try anything in the tutorials I see, it doesn't work. I always get erors such as "No route matches [GET] "/packs/js/" or "No route matches [GET] "/assets/...".

Here's what my default.conf looks like :

```
upstream railsapp {
  server hubsite:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /app/public;

    # Deny requests for files that should never be accessed  
    location ~ /\. {    
        deny all;  
    }
    location ~* ^.+\.(rb|log|go|exe)$ {    
        deny all;  
    }

    try_files $uri @rails;

    # serve static (compiled) assets directly if they exist (for rails production)
    location ~ ^/(assets|packs|images|javascripts|stylesheets|swfs|system)/ {
        try_files $uri @rails;
        access_log off;
        gzip_static on;
        
        # to serve pre-gzipped version
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        
        add_header Last-Modified "";
        add_header ETag "";
        break;
    }

    location @rails {
        proxy_pass http://railsapp;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    # 404 HANDLING
    location = /404.html {
        internal;
    }
}
```

I also tried to modify the proxy_pass for my proper url, but it didn't work. Basically, there would always be a "/portal/" after the url, so like "mytestwebsite.com/portal/signin". All of this is running in a docker container and the root path does seem to be correct from what I checked.

If anyone has an idea as to why it doesn't work, feel free to point me in the good direction! Thanks!

Comment: Could you please confirm that all assets were compiled successfully?
In my opinion possible reasons:
- files do not exist
or nginx does not have access to files.

You can also check nginx error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was fine with nginx, problem was that I wasn't properly linking my volumes with my docker-compose!